# github.com pull request incorrectly merges base into branch before PR completed

Tags: git, github, merge

We had a pull request on GitHub.com do something very weird. We were initiating a PR to merge a `54.1` release branch into the next release branch, `54.2` (`54.2` <- `54.1`).  But before the PR was complete, github.com completed a merge the opposite way, `54.1` <- `54.2`, incorrectly including next release's code into the `54.1` branch. Does anyone know why it would do this?

- Base branch: `54.2`
- Feature branch `54.1`
- PR initiated from github.com
- Source of `54.2` was master:
- Source of `54.1` was `54.0`. The source of `54.0` was `master`

Branches

```
master-----------------------------
   \          /   \          /
    --54.0---      --54.2-- / ------
            \         /    /
             --54.1-x------
```

Note: `x` above was a cherry pick commit added to 54.1 from another branch that was not in 54.2. Hence why the need for the initial PR

`60912a3a` is the commit in question.  Why did this happen?
[image]

You can see `f9fbd7de` above this commit, at the same timestamp, is the PR `54.2` <- `54.1` PR that was correctly merged once the PR was completed.
[image]

Additional notes

- Both commits' committers were `GitHub.com`. Based on my research it seems github.com was the integrator of the author's code.
- No local commits, merges or pushes occurred on 54.2, the developer didn't even know he could do merges locally. Everything was done from GitHub.com
- The developer didn't update the base branch via the ui using the "branch is out of date, update branch" button [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/keeping-your-pull-request-in-sync-with-the-base-branch#updating-your-pull-request-branch)